# Falha no PowerShell, ele não pode ser inicializado, arquivo bloqueado por politicas de restrição de software, como corrigir?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, windows-10

Fui utilizar o package manager console no Visual Studio 2015, ao abrir o powershell apareceu uma mensagem se eu queria executar ele em um arquivo de fonte não confiável, eu cliquei sim em mostrou esta mensagem mais umas 3 vezes, cliquei sim nas três vezes e depois apareceu esta outra mensagem.

Traduzindo para o português a mensagem resumida é esta:

> O shell não pode ser iniciado, ocorreu uma falha durante a sua inicialização: Ocorreu erros ao carregar arquivos de dados de formato Microsoft.Powershell.Core, C:\windows...\certificate.format.ps1.xml, o arquivo foi ignorado devido à seguinte exceção de validação: O arquivo C:\windows...\certificate.format.ps1.xml não pode ser carregado por políticas de restrição de software como aquelas criadas com a política de grupo

Como consertar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

A política de execução padrão do PowerShell é um pouco restritiva mesmo, você pode ver qual a política de restrição que está ativa com o cmdlet

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

E você pode usar o cmdlet `Set-ExecutionPolicy` para mudá-la

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

`RemoteSigned` funciona na maioria dos casos, ela só é mais restritiva que a `Unrestricted`.

Obs.: Não esqueça de abrir o PowerShell como administrador.

Mais detalhes em [Using the Set-ExecutionPolicy Cdmlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee176961.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)<sup>(en)</sup>

Comment: Eu já tinha realizado esta operação de executionpolicy antes de postar aqui no stackoverflow e continuou dando a mesma  mensagem de erro no powershel. Eu tentei fazer mais coisas pesquizando no google, como resetar as politicas de grupo do windows10 através de comandos no prompt, desinstalei o visual studio porém sem sucesso. Não sei se há uma forma de restaurar o powershell no window10, que vêm na versão 5.0, não encontrei nada, nem em fóruns gringos, só há maneiras de desinstalar no windows 7 e em versões anteriores, não encontrei nada do windows 10.

Comment: Já resolvi o problema aqui, eu atualizei o meu Windows10 para a sua última versão e o powershell voltou ao normal.